# Why delimiter used with stored procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand, why delimiter used with stored procedure in mysql?
but i couldn't.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts()
   BEGIN
       SELECT *  FROM products;
   END //
DELIMITER ;`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql's default delimiter is `;` which is used for one statement in the command line , something as

```
select * from users ;
```

When you write a trigger or stored procedure to execute the entire code mysql needs to understand that its a block of code/query.

If no delimiter is provided then when mysql encounters any `;` inside the store procedure or trigger it will think that as one statement and will try to execute it. So we need to provide a delimiter for store procedure or trigger and make mysql understand that anything within that delimiter is one complete set of code.

So in your example

```
SELECT * FROM products;
```

it will be a part of the complete statement when there is a delimiter other than `;` is provided at the beginning.