# MYSQL Stored Procedure - Can not create procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, routines

Now trying to create a new procedure as root user with some additional parameters

```
DELIMITER //
USE `user_main_table`;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_user_temp;
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE insert_user_temp()
 BEGIN 
  DECLARE row_coun_no INT;
  SELECT COUNT(`id`) INTO row_coun_no FROM user_temp;
  IF row_coun_no != 0 THEN
    TRUNCATE `user_data`;
    INSERT INTO user_data (employee_id,employee_code,employment_type,`emp_name`,first_name,middle_name,last_name,photo_file_name,email_id)
    SELECT employee_id,`employee_code`,`employment_type`,CONCAT(`first_name`," ",`last_name`),`first_name`,`middle_name`,`last_name`, `email_id`, `photo_file_name` FROM `user_temp`;
    TRUNCATE user_temp;
    UPDATE  `demo_user`.`tbl_users`, `user_main_table`.`user_data` SET tbl_users.profile_pic = user_data.photo_file_name
  END IF;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

Executing above deletes the old procedure but does not create new with additional params defined

Running SP through phpmyadmin

[image]

**UPDATED PROCEDURE**

```
USE `user_main_table`;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_user_temp;
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE insert_user_temp()
 BEGIN 
  DECLARE row_coun_no INT;
  SELECT COUNT(`id`) INTO row_coun_no FROM user_temp;
  IF row_coun_no != 0 THEN
    TRUNCATE `user_data`;
    INSERT INTO user_data (employee_id,employee_code,employment_type,`emp_name`,first_name,middle_name,last_name,photo_file_name,email_id)
    SELECT employee_id,`employee_code`,`employment_type`,CONCAT(`first_name`," ",`last_name`),`first_name`,`middle_name`,`last_name`, `email_id`, `photo_file_name` FROM `user_temp`;
    TRUNCATE user_temp;
    UPDATE  `demo_user`.`tbl_users`, `user_main_table`.`user_data` SET tbl_users.profile_pic = user_data.photo_file_name
  END IF;
END;
```

**Executing Procedure using mysql termial**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_user_temp_to_user()
BEGIN 
DECLARE row_coun_no INT;
SELECT COUNT(`id`) INTO row_coun_no FROM user_temp;
IF row_coun_no != 0 THEN
TRUNCATE `user_hrms`;
INSERT INTO user_hrms (employee_id,employee_code,employment_type,`emp_name`,first_name,middle_name,last_name,reporting_authority,department,designation,gender,location_name,branch_id,mobile_number,extension_number,email_id,`status`,`birthdate`,`anniversary`,`photo_file_name`,mtd,ytd,experience ,primary_skills,secondary_skills,joining_date,bu,award_category,award_category_desc)
SELECT employee_id,`employee_code`,`employment_type`,CONCAT(`first_name`," ",`last_name`),`first_name`,`middle_name`,`last_name`,`reporting_authority`,`department`,`designation`,`gender`,`location_name`,`branch_id`,`mobile_number`,`extension_number`,`email_id`,`status`,`birthdate`,`anniversary`,`photo_file_name`,mtd,ytd,experience,primary_skills,secondary_skills,joining_date,bu,award_category,award_category_desc FROM `user_temp`; 
TRUNCATE user_temp;
UPDATE `demo_intranet`.`tbl_users`, `intranet`.`user_hrms` SET tbl_users.profile_pic = user_hrms.photo_file_name
WHERE tbl_users.email = user_hrms.email_id;
END IF;
END;//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

If someone could help me understand what I am doing incorrectly here, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Few issues with the syntax

- You are missing the delimiter
- The procedure name is missing braces `()`

---

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_user_temp()
 BEGIN 
  DECLARE row_coun_no INT;
  SELECT COUNT(`id`) INTO row_coun_no FROM user_temp;
  IF row_coun_no != 0 THEN
    TRUNCATE `user_data`;
    INSERT INTO user_data (employee_id,employee_code,employment_type,`emp_name`,first_name,middle_name,last_name,photo_file_name,email_id)
    SELECT employee_id,`employee_code`,`employment_type`,CONCAT(`first_name`," ",`last_name`),`first_name`,`middle_name`,`last_name`, `email_id`, `photo_file_name` FROM `user_temp`;
    TRUNCATE user_temp;
    UPDATE  `demo_user`.`tbl_users`, `main_user`.`user_data` SET tbl_users.profile_pic = user_data.photo_file_name
    WHERE  tbl_users.email = user_data.email_id;
  END IF;
END;//

delimiter ;
```

Just tested in mysql terminal and it works for  me

```
mysql> use test ;
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE insert_user_temp()
    ->  BEGIN 
    ->   DECLARE row_coun_no INT;
    ->   SELECT COUNT(`id`) INTO row_coun_no FROM user_temp;
    ->   IF row_coun_no != 0 THEN
    ->     TRUNCATE `user_data`;
    ->     INSERT INTO user_data (employee_id,employee_code,employment_type,`emp_name`,first_name,middle_name,last_name,photo_file_name,email_id)
    ->     SELECT employee_id,`employee_code`,`employment_type`,CONCAT(`first_name`," ",`last_name`),`first_name`,`middle_name`,`last_name`, `email_id`, `photo_file_name` FROM `user_temp`;
    ->     TRUNCATE user_temp;
    ->     UPDATE  `demo_user`.`tbl_users`, `main_user`.`user_data` SET tbl_users.profile_pic = user_data.photo_file_name
    ->     WHERE  tbl_users.email = user_data.email_id;
    ->   END IF;
    -> END;//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

For PHPMyadmin you do not need the delimiter section in the code rather you can select them from the user interface.

Comment: Being a newbie, I do not understand what exactly should be passed in delimiter ?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228490/why-delimiter-used-with-stored-procedure-in-mysql/29228588#29228588, so you can use `$$` or `//` for your delimiter as you wish. You choose something which may not appear in the query.

Comment: Done with what you said, but now `Unknown table 'user_temp'` though it exists under DB `main_user` Is this related to sotred procedure error ?

Comment: Also check that the procedure is created under proper user, say you created a procedure as `root` and trying to remove this with some other user the procedure will not be deleted.

Comment: Is `user_temp` is a temporary table ? Remember  temporary tables exists for the current connection.

Comment: User access is correct and trying to `Run SQL query/queries on database information_schema:` `user_temp ` is a table under DB `main_user`

Comment: Also can not see procedure deleted from `ROUTINES` table though I have  tried deleting it

Comment: Just to make clear procedure is a part of database not table, run this command `SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS;` this will show the existing procedures and for which DB it is, try it as root user.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: user_temp table should exists in same db where your procedure other wise add db also with table name in your query or use db before your statment.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty given your inputs, I have modified my SP. Could you pls check it once as it deletes the old SP but does not create

Comment: @ZafarMalik, `user_temp` table exists in same DB

Comment: Are you running the the procedure create statement from mysql terminal or from some other tool like phpmyadmin ? if not running from terminal then you need to check the delimiter setup in those, I guess you can setup the delimiter there directly and then by removing it from the create part.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, `Runing SQL query/queries on server "localhost": ` using phpmyadmin. Attached image from where it is being executed and checking SP details under `information_schema »ROUTINES`

Comment: Yes then you need to set the delimiter in the delimiter section and then remove `delimiter //` and `END;//` to `END;` and finally no need to have the last line `delimiter ;` In the delimiter section just add or select `//` or anything other than `;`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty pls see my updated SP as you mentioned. Error `CREATE DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE insert_user_temp( ) BEGIN DECLARE row_coun_no INT;` How can I set delimiter ?

Comment: You need to remove backticks for root and localhost and should be as `CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE insert_user_temp()`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, I updated to what you said but it still throws same exception.

Comment: Hmm its hard for me to test since I do not have phpmyadmin and I usually run on mysql terminal and I just ran the procedure and it works for me. Let me update that to the answer what I did.