# Stored procedure insert query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This is my code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_new_user(IN VARCHAR(30) UName)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `tbl_user_details` (`Name`) VALUES(UName);
END
```

When I run this query it shows an error

**Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1**

Please give me the correction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why delimiter used with stored procedure in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228490/why-delimiter-used-with-stored-procedure-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER//
USE db_name//
CREATE PROCEDURE add_new_user(IN UName VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `tbl_user_details` (`Name`) VALUES(UName);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is only 1 statement in the procedure you don't need to set delimiters or use begin..end statements.

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop procedure if exists p;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> CREATE PROCEDURE p(IN UName VARCHAR(30) )
    -> INSERT INTO `tbl_user_details` (`Name`) VALUES(UName);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> show create procedure p;
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Procedure | sql_mode                                   | Create Procedure                                                                                                             | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| p         | STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION | CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `p`(IN UName VARCHAR(30) )
INSERT INTO `tbl_user_details` (`Name`) VALUES(UName) | cp850                | cp850_general_ci     | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+-----------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```